# JAXB: xjc doesn't create file from specific xsd file

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc

There are 5 files with xsd schemas here: http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2016/01/25/eD/DefinicjeTypy/.

3 of them are correctly parsed and compiled but I have a big problem with other 2.Here is one of them
http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2016/01/25/eD/DefinicjeTypy/KodyUrzedowSkarbowych_v4-0E.xsd

I use command like this:

```
 xjc -p jpk -b binding.xjb KodyUrzedowSkarbowych_v4-0E.xsd
```

Unfortunately xjc compiler doesn't create any classes for those two.
I have also solved problem with default limitation of enumeration type by using global binding - binding.xjb, because there are 400 elements.
But still, I don't have any idea why  I don't get any classes from those two files.

Answer (score 0):

The XML Schema `KodyUrzedowSkarbowych_v4-0E.xsd` doesn't produce an enum because all values are numeric, which isn't possible as a Java enum member name. (Try prefixing all value="0202" etc. with an 'x'- it compiles.)

To resolve, you'll have to add an another customizing mantra within each (!) 
`<xsd:enumeration value="x0202">`, like this:

```
<xsd:annotation><xsd:appinfo>
<jaxb:typesafeEnumMember> 
    name = "x0202" value="0202"
</jaxb:typesafeEnumMember>
</xsd:annotation></xsd:appinfo>
```

Probably write an XSLT to automatize this, or use sed, or a Perl script...

I didn't check the other file since you didn't name it.